# Show that the sum of magnitude of vectors is equal to the minus of the sum of dot products

Tags: vectors

I came across this question whilst doing some revision for an upcoming test and I became completely stuck on this question:

$$
\begin{array}{l}\text { Let } a, b \text { and } c \text { be non-zero vectors with a vector sum equal to zero. By } \\ \text { considering the dot product, show that } \\ \qquad|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}+|c|^{2}=-2(a \cdot b+b \cdot c+c \cdot a)\end{array}
$$

I've done a question similar to this but involving roots of unity i.e.

$$\text{Prove that} \quad z_1^1+z_2^2+\dots +z_n^2=z_1z_2+z_2z_3+\dots z_{n-1}z_n$$

And I started by letting $z_1=a, z_2=b, z_3=c$ but I think I'm doing this completely wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Plug $c=-a-b$ into the equation and simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(a+b+c)=\mathbf{0}$$
$$(a+b+c)^2=0$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca=0$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=-2ab-2bc-2ca$$